# how to combine day of week and day of month in crontab?

Tags: linux, cron

I want to run some jobs on day 1 of each month and others on day 1 of each week, but what if both collide? In this case the month should have precedence. How do I tell this cron?

```
# run on every day 1 of each month:
59 12 1 * * user script_month

# run on every day 1 of each week:
59 12 * * 1 user script_week
```

*EDIT 1*:

There is an answer that uses "IF" which is a good workaround.

What about this:

```
# run on every day 1 of each week:
59 12 2-31 * 1 user script_week
```

Maybe it also does what I am asking for? (run on all weeks on day 1 except if it is day 1 of the month)

*Edit 2:*

I found this:

"If both [date] fields are restricted (i.e., aren't *), the command will be run when *either* field matches the current time." (source: http://thewatertower.org.uk/news/000160/crontab_the_first_five_fields_combine_to_restrict_the_schedule_except_for_when_they_dont.html )

Seems it is not possible like I wrote in Edit 1?

Comment: It is not correct that non-* entries match if for any match of the fields, the run if *all* of them match.  For example "0 0 * * *" runs at exactly midnight, not for every minute between 00:00-00:59 *OR* on the hour for every hour 00 through 23.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have `script_week` check whether it is running on day 1 of the month. If it is, then have it exit before doing any real work. For example, in a bash script, such a check might look like this:

```
if [ `/bin/date +%d` = "01" ]; then exit 0; fi
```

If you prefer, you could leave `script_week` unmodified, and instead put a similar check into the `crontab` entry for `script_week`, something like this:

```
59 12 * * 1 user if [ `/bin/date +\%d` != "01" ]; then script_week; fi
```

Answer (score 3):

If it is a long running job, you could also consider having the script use a lock-file so that only one instance of it will run at a time.  Then you could have it listed in both cron entries, and rely on it detecting when one is already running.

This can also be useful if it's a VERY long running job.  Sometimes I've run across cron jobs that usually don't take very long, but if the system is running under a high load processing logs or a big job, it might take longer than expected.  Then if multiple of these jobs start at the same time, they can start stacking up and eventually bring the machine to it's knees.

Unlikely for a job that runs once a week, but it is a good habit to get into -- preventing jobs from stacking up, and it would do double duty to prevent the job from being run from both crontab entries.